# Data exchange QGIS SQL

Tags: qgis, mariadb

I am a new user of QGIS. I was surprised how easy it is to visualize data from a SQL database in QGIS.
Now I wonder if it is possible that changes in the database can be passed on directly to QGIS. Even better would be the reverse way. Where can I find information about this?

At the moment I use MariaDB 10 and QGIS 2.18.13

Comment: Do you mean you want to edit your database within QGIS? Please give more details on the database you use and QGIS version...

Comment: Frank - absolutely. Any data value change made at the SQL/Database level requires only a slight pan of the map to see the changes. Any schema changes to the table can be applied by only refreshing the layer using the ChangeDataSources plugin... we live by this!

Comment: DPSSpatial - That sounds good! I will try it.

Comment: At the moment I use MariaDB 10 and QGIS 2.18.13

Comment: @FrankSimonis we use both PostGIS and MS SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

Yes, data changes can be passed on both ways. If you have e.g. a PostGIS data source added to the canvas, changes in the data table will be shown on the map e.g. if you refresh the connection or pan the layer in QGIS.

Vice versa, if you edit features using the main toolbar, edits will be saved to the database.